# PyQt4 Dynamically created radiobuttons and default checking

Tags: python, pyqt, radio-button, pyqt4

I want to dynamically create radiobuttons for every year from 2013. I've already created these buttons but I am not able to check the first radiobutton(2013). To do that I am using `QtGui.QRadioButton('2013').setChecked(True)`

I have no idea what I am missing...

```
def dynamicaly_cratede_radiobtns(self):
    current_year = datetime.today().year
    self.button_group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()

    for i in range(2013, current_year+1):
        self.button_name = QtGui.QRadioButton("{}".format(i))
        self.button_name.setObjectName("radiobtn_{}".format(i))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_name)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.button_name,i)
        self.button_name.toggled.connect(self.subplot_year)

    QtGui.QRadioButton('2013').setChecked(True)

def subplot_year(self):
    print self.button_group.checkedId()
```

**EDIT**
I just solved it by using **if**

```
        for i in range(2013, current_year+1):
        self.button_name = QtGui.QRadioButton("{}".format(i))
        self.button_name.setObjectName("radiobtn_{}".format(i))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_name)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.button_name,i)
        self.button_name.toggled.connect(self.subplot_year)
        if i == 2013:
            self.button_name.setChecked(True)
```

But anyway, why does the original approach doesn't work? I think it is more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QtGui.QRadioButton('2013').setChecked(True)
```

creates a new radio button with text value of `'2013'`. This one gets checked.

This radio button is not part of any layout or radio group and thus non of the buttons is checked.

It seems like you think the radio buttons get cached somewhere and can be accessed with the text value. But this is not the case.

To solve this issue you need to check one of the buttons you added to the layout like you did in your edit.